# Run python or javascript file from postgres function?

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql

How i can Run python or javascript file from postgres function ?

I have two postgres data base with totally different structure .

but i need to sync that two databases .

I will write the script that will read data from local data base and write into server data base in any language (python , java , javascript, node).

but the main problem is :

I do not know how to call that script from postgres procedure or function .

so the ques is :

**How we can call or run any script from postgres procedure ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `plperl`, `plpython` or `pljava` and use the system utils of the language. I.e in plpython use `subprocess`, in java use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` and so on:

For example in `plpython`:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu; -- create language if does not exist

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION venue.test_execute()
  RETURNS void AS
  $BODY$
  import subprocess
  subprocess.call(['/path/to/script/test.py'])

  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpythonu;

SELECT venue.test_execute();
```

**CONSIDERATIONS**

Actually you can launch a script from a Postgres function, but this is not the preferred way to synchronize data between databases. You probably will have issues related to absolute and relative paths to scripts and data, and file system permissions. Instead use a database function to export data in a known format and call your synchronize script from outside the database. Another options is use the [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/dblink.html) module.

Comment: i am trying to install plpythonu by this command : sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.4 postgresql-plpython-9.4 but its not working

Comment: Use this command: `aptitude search plpython` and check the list of the available packages for your system

Comment: I have big list :          postgres-xc-plpython   - PL/Python procedural language fo
p   postgres-xc-plpython:i - PL/Python procedural language fo
v   postgresql-plpython    -                                 
v   postgresql-plpython:i3 -                                 
p   postgresql-plpython-8. - PL/Python procedural language fo
. . . 

p   postgresql-plpython-9. - PL/Python procedural language fo
. . . . 
v   postgresql-plpython3:i -                                 
p   postgresql-plpython3-9 - PL/Python 3 procedural language 
. . . .

Comment: I have the package `postgresql-plpython-9.3` installed.

Comment: Now what i need to do

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install postgresql-plpython-9.3`. If it does not work, please ask another question, maybe here: http://askubuntu.com.

Comment: i put that question in [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/690472/error-could-not-access-file-libdir-plpython2-no-such-file-or-directory)  and also at [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361867/error-could-not-access-file-libdir-plpython2-no-such-file-or-directory)   with detail explanation  . Please take a look .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Perl Function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plperl-funcs.html) and in that call your script to sync the databases.